# What is the difference between providedIn: 'Root' than using a service as a provider at the app component?

Tags: angular

If I set a service as a provider at the app module (root module) or at the decorator @Injectable use providedIn: 'root', I assume that I will achieve the same behavior in both cases. That means all my application will "see" the same singleton class provided by the root module.

But If I don't set any module at the @Injectable decorator on the service and use that class as a provider at the app component module, I am not able to see that same service within components that are not 'created' by my template. For example, I can't use that service inside a MatDialog, that is created and opened using TS and not my template.

That being said, what is the technical difference between those approaches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They introduced `providedIn: 'root'` to make it easier to manage services. Most services are stateless singleton services. `providedIn: 'root'` is essentially the same as just adding the service at the app.module level in the providers array. However, it was easy to forget to add this entry and an unnecessary extra step.

Obviously, if you don't want a singleton service and would rather provide stateful services at various levels then the providers array is still available. It would be confusing to scrap it at the app.module level just because `providedIn: root` covers this.

Comment: But why if I use the providers array at the app decorator I have different behavior of that service comparing to use the providers array at the module app or the service @Injectable? What makes those declarations different?

Comment: If a component provides DI objects, these objects are only visible (injectable) in child components. Using MatDailog creates new component instance which is not a child of AppComponent, and thus your service is not available there. From [docs](https://angular.io/guide/providers#providing-services-in-modules-vs-components): "Generally, provide services the whole application needs in the root module [...] Register a provider with a component when you must limit a service instance to a component and its component tree, that is, its child components."